# Get the value of a shiny embedded input on a DT table?

Tags: input, shiny, datatable

I need to access the selected value from an DT embedded input, but I have not been able to make it work.  Here is the problem in a nutshell:

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  DTOutput("table"),
  verbatimTextOutput("selected")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  TableData <- reactive({
  
    data <- data.frame(col1 = 1:5)
    
      for(i in 1:5) {
      data$options[i] <- as.character(selectInput(paste0("sel", i), "",
                                                       choices = c("One" = 1, "Two" = 2, "Three" = 3)))
      return(data)
      }
    })

  output$table <- renderDataTable(
      
        TableData(), escape = FALSE, selection = 'none',
        callback = JS("table.rows().every(function(i, tab, row) {
            var $this = $(this.node());
            $this.attr('id', this.data()[0]);
            $this.addClass('shiny-input-container');
          });
          Shiny.unbindAll(table.table().node());
          Shiny.bindAll(table.table().node());")
      )
    
  output$selected <- renderPrint({
    
    datos <- TableData()
    
    for(i in 1:nrow(datos)) {
      paste(input[[paste0("sel", i)]])
    }
    return(datos) #Not giving expected output
  })
  
  }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I would greatly appreciate some feedback on how to call those values, either for their value or their label.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what is being defined in the initial DT `table`. Also, `input$sel1` is `NULL`; as are all `input$seli`.

If the intention is to have users select some information, and then put that into a dataframe or data table and use it for further analysis, one way to do this is given below.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  DTOutput("table")
  ,verbatimTextOutput("selected")
  ,uiOutput("uidata")
  ,DTOutput("selected1")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  howmany <- reactiveVal(5)  ## define a reactive for how many selectinputs to be defined
  
  TableData <- reactive({
    data <- data.frame(col1 = 1:howmany())
    for(i in 1:howmany()) {
      data$options[i] <- as.character(selectInput(paste0("sel", i), "",
                                                  choices = c("One" = 1, "Two" = 2, "Three" = 3),
                                                  selected=1
                                                  ))
      return(data)
    }
  })
  
  output$table <- renderDataTable(
    
    TableData(), escape = FALSE, selection = 'none',
    callback = JS("table.rows().every(function(i, tab, row) {
            var $this = $(this.node());
            $this.attr('id', this.data()[0]);
            $this.addClass('shiny-input-container');
          });
          Shiny.unbindAll(table.table().node());
          Shiny.bindAll(table.table().node());")
  )
  
  output$selected <- renderPrint({
    print(input$sel1)
  })
  
  output$uidata <- renderUI({  
    lapply(1:howmany(), function(i) {
      selectInput(paste0("mysel", i), "", 
                  choices = c("One" = 1, "Two" = 2, "Three" = 3, "apple"=4),
                  selected=4
      )
    })
  })
  
  datos <- reactive({
    dat <- data.frame(col1=c(),newcol=c())
    lapply(1:howmany(), function(i){
      q <- paste0("mysel",i)
      uivar  <- expr('$'(input,!!q))
      req(uivar)
      val <- eval_tidy(uivar)
      dat <<- rbind(dat,data.frame(col1=i,newcol=val[[1]]))
    })
    dat
  })
  
  output$selected1 <- renderDataTable(datos(), escape = FALSE)
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```